# Как избавить страницы от лишнего кода?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Можно ли создать отдельные блоки header/content/footer в разных html файлах, чтобы после соединить их на одной странице? Иногда приходится менять какой-то из повторяющихся блоков на нескольких страницах, что не удобно. Вероятно есть какое-то решение этой проблемы.

Comment: Решения вроде есть, но обычно такое делают ещё на стороне веб-сервера с помощью какого-нибудь шаблонизатора

Comment: Можно. Есть решение. Называется шаблонизаторы

Comment: @Утка чтобы на стороне браузера и без js (судя по его отсутствию в тегах), с шаблонизаторами пока туго)

Comment: @andreymal, вообще да, условия "толкьо клиент и нет js" - какие-то жесткие и искуственные, как сделать при таких условиях я не знаю)

Comment: Без js и на стороне браузера - xslt, но поверьте, лучше js и шаблонизатор. Если совсем просто, то можно сдуть пыль с http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html но это на стороне сервера

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov, хей, настройки вебсервера к клиенту относить нечестно) А вот xslt да, об этом я не подумал

Comment: Почему бы не использовать просто вставку по типу include где указывать разные блоки сайтов?

Comment: @GuitarFan потому что такого в браузерах (если без js) ещё просто нет. Разве что ифреймы, но это кривота и годится далеко не всегда

Comment: Наверное шаблонизаторы изучать будет дольше, чем просто создать php скрипт и загружать части кода методом <?php include_once 'code1.php' ?>

Comment: @GuitarFan php это и есть один из шаблонизаторов :D Его и юзайте, если вас это устраивает

Answer (score 3):

Для этого используется [gulp-rigger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rigger)

**Установка:**

```
npm i –g gulp
npm i --save-dev gulp
npm i --save-dev gulp-rigger
```

**gulpfile.js**:

```
'use strict'; // Проверка строк кода

// Плагины
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    rigger       = require('gulp-rigger');

// Работа с HTML 
gulp.task('html', function(){
    gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(rigger())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});

// Наблюдение
gulp.task('watch', function () {    
    gulp.watch(path.watch.html, ['html']);
});

// Задачи по-умолчанию
gulp.task('default', [
    'html'  
]);
```

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test-pj</title>
....
</head>
<body>
  //= template/header.html <!-- Подключение header с помощью gulp-rigger -->
  <main> <h1>hello, world</h1> </main>
  //= template/footer.html <!-- Подключение footer с помощью gulp-rigger -->

</body>
</html>
```

**Структура:**

```
www
  |__ app
        |__ template
                   |__ header.html
                   |__ footer.html
        |__ index.html

  |__ dist
        |__ index.html
```

[Моя сборка](https://github.com/lime7/www)

Comment: Почему бы не использовать просто вставку по типу include где указывать разные блоки сайтов?

Comment: @GuitarFan, потому что ознакомьтесь с html разметкой. "Просто include" в html не предусмотрен.

Comment: Наверное шаблонизаторы изучать будет дольше, чем просто создать php скрипт и загружать части кода методом <?php include_once 'code1.php' ?>

Comment: вопрос был по html

Comment: Ага, вот так стало просто отлично. К сожалению, второго плюса поставить не могу. :)

Answer (score 3):

Во избежание дублирования `html` кода нужно использовать шаблонизатор, а чтобы ускорить написание `html` кода, поможет `html-предпроцессор`, все это вы можете найти в [**Jade**](http://jadelang.net). Источников вдохновения для которого послужил старый добрый [**Haml**](http://haml.info).

**`Jade`**-синтаксис:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
    script(type='text/javascript').
      if (foo) {
         bar(1 + 5)
      }
  body
    h1 Jade - node template engine
    #container.col
      if youAreUsingJade
        p You are amazing
      else
        p Get on it!
      p.
        Jade is a terse and simple
        templating language with a
        strong focus on performance
        and powerful features.
```

**`HTML`**-синтаксис:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Jade</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (foo) {
         bar(1 + 5)
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Jade - node template engine</h1>
    <div id="container" class="col">
      <p>You are amazing</p>
      <p>
        Jade is a terse and simple
        templating language with a
        strong focus on performance
        and powerful features.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Пример подключения (`include`) в `Jade`:

```
include footer.jade
include data/copyright.html
```

Почему именно **`Jade`**?:

- работает на клиентской стороне
- отличная читабельность
- гибкая система отступов
- раскрытие блоков
- примеси
- статические инклюды
- интерполяция в аттрибутах
- из соображений безопасности по умолчанию все экранируется
- контекстные сообщения об ошибках как во время компиляции так и во
  время выполнения
- утилита для компиляции jade в html из командной строки
- режим HTML5 (используйте doctype !!! 5)
- кеширование в памяти (опционально)
- комбинирование динамических и статических CSS-классов
- манипуляции с деревом парсинга через filters
- поддержка Express JS “из коробки”
- прозрачный механизм итерации по объектам, массивам, и даже
  неисчислимым типам через each
- блочные комментарии
- фильтры AST
- фильтры
- скринкасты

ps. Для всего этого нужно знать `Node.js`, если вы не знакомы с ним, все проблемы решит данное [**видео**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCsFDi1cQIk). Чем дальше, тем больше.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой шаблонизатор, поддерживаемый многими популярными http-серверами без каких либо дополнительных программ - [Server Side Includes](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Пример файла index.shtml :

```
<!--# include file="header.html" -->
<!--# include file="main-content.html" -->
<!--# include file="footer.html" -->
```

В результате клиенту выдаётся конкатенация трёх файлов.